# Tournament-Systems creating driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drivers, tournament

Now that the error has been fixed by adding `require 'tournament_system'` here is my new error:

This is the terminal:

```
  Rendering html template
  Rendered html template (0.0ms)
  Rendered tourneys/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.8ms)
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 16ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)



RuntimeError - Not Implemented:
  app/controllers/tourneys_controller.rb:77:in `tourn'
  app/views/tourneys/index.html.erb:37:in `_app_views_tourneys_index_html_erb__1482772099755741577_70314301318160'

Started POST "/__better_errors/deabb75178ea93ac/variables" for ::1 at 2018-04-17 00:55:03 -0700
```

This is on the webpage

```
Not Implemented

tournapp/controllers/tourneys_controller.rb
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
  def tourn
    driver = Driver.new
   # Generate a round of a single elimination tournament
    TournamentSystem::SingleElimination.generate driver
    #Challonge::Tournament.find(:all)
    #@teamArray2 = render html: "<div>#{Challonge::Tournament.find(:all)}</div>".html_safe
  end
>>
 This is a live shell. Type in here.
Request info
Request parameters  
{"controller"=>"tourneys", "action"=>"index"}
Rack session    
(object too large. Modify ActionDispatch::Request::Session#inspect or increase BetterErrors.maximum_variable_inspect_size)
Local Variables
driver  
#<Driver:0x00007fe6a4eba5e0>
```

I believe the error has to do with not calling the driver correctly. Also I created the controller Tourney using a scaffold.

Comment: Could you share the complete stack trace of the error?

Comment: I am sorry for the dumb question but how do I do that?

Comment: When you receive the error, there will be more lines with details about the error and where the error is occurring. It will mostly follow the error message. Sharing that will help pin point the error.

Comment: I edited my post to show the errors. I am hoping this what you are refering to. Thanks for the help.

Comment: From what I understand the gem `tournament-system` has been installed but not explicitly required in your `driver.rb`. Try adding `require 'tournament-system'` before `class Driver` and see if that helps.

Comment: ok I did that but now I am getting the error: cannot load such file -- tournament-system

Comment: Look at this sample test driver - https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system/blob/master/spec/support/test_driver.rb

Change the require to `require 'tournament_system'`. That should do it

Comment: Perfect!! However, there is a new error: Not Implemented

    `def tourn
    driver = Driver.new
   # Generate a round of a single elimination tournament
    TournamentSystem::SingleElimination.generate driver
    #Challonge::Tournament.find(:all)
    #@teamArray2 = render html: "<div>#{Challonge::Tournament.find(:all)}</div>".html_safe
  end`

Comment: I think your `def tournament` has an extra `end`

Comment: I dont think so I just took another look. I believe all the ends are in the right spot and without any extra ones.

Comment: You have used `Tourney.all`. Is there a model named `Tourney`? Can you update the question with the new findings and stacktrace?

Comment: I have updated my question. Also yes I do have a model named Tourney but it was created with the scaffold and theres nothing in it. Also the Tourney.All has nothing to really do with the tournament_system part. That was something else I was working on which I got working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Class Driver` was inhereting from `TournamentSystem::Driver` but that module was not available as it was not explicitly required.

Adding `require 'tournament_system'` should take care of that.

---

Regarding the `NotImplemented` error, this is not related to your code. If you follow the source code of `def generate` in `module SingleElimination` ([source code](https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system/blob/aeb4a3fba5d2e98b13916564ff4c122036c1ae1a/lib/tournament_system/single_elimination.rb#L13)) and traverse:

[def generate](https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system/blob/aeb4a3fba5d2e98b13916564ff4c122036c1ae1a/lib/tournament_system/single_elimination.rb#L24) calls [create_matches](https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system/blob/master/lib/tournament_system/driver.rb#L204) which calls [create_match](https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system/blob/master/lib/tournament_system/driver.rb#L192) which finally calls [build_match](https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system/blob/master/lib/tournament_system/driver.rb#L144) and that has a `raise 'Not Implemented'`.

The Developer of the project has not completed implementing all the required functions.

Comment: Oh damn I see. So it looks like this gem wont work for my needs since it is not completed. Can you recommend a tutorial or gem that can do single elimination tournaments or any other tournaments besides round robin. As I already got that working with the round-robin gem as you can see in the def tournament section.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you there as I have never worked with tournament systems before. You could get in touch with the developer of the project to check if they are going to finish implementing this soon.

Comment: Yea very true. Well thank you for your help. I really appriciate it as I've spent a couple of weeks trying to figure this out.